# What is the mask output parameter of findFundamentalMat?

Tags: opencv

findFundamentalMat has an optional output parameter labelled 'mask'. There is no description of what mask represents in the current OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

My question is, what does the mask output parameter represent in OpenCV's findFundamentalMat function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably its a map/mask to see which points were used (inlier). In the other languages the parameter is called "status"

from doc:

status – Output array of N elements, every element of which is set to 0 for outliers and to 1 for the other points. The array is computed only in the RANSAC and LMedS methods. For other methods, it is set to all 1’s.

so probably it just wasnt renamed (forgotten)?

Comment: let me know if correction needed to  documentation of OpenCV

Comment: @sturkmen I couldnt test it myself, but in the doc is the mask parameter of c++ function not documented. I'm very optimistic that it is identical to the documented "status" parameter.

Comment: i think you are right as seen [docs.opencv.org/master](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga30ccb52f4e726daa039fd5cb5bf0822b). i will make a PR to correct it. thank you.